# Avoid heredoc regex escape

Tags: ruby

I have a heredoc which has a regular expression on it:

```
((\d)(\3))
```

When it's evaluated, the \3 is escaped:

```
p(<<~RUBY)
  /((\w)(/\3))/
RUBY
# "/((w)(/\u0003))/"
```

How can I avoid that and just render it as it is? I mean:

```
p(<<~RUBY)
  /((\w)(/\3))/
RUBY
# => "/((w)(/\3))/"
```

I've tried using:

```
p(<<~'RUBY')
  /((\w)(/\3))/
RUBY
# "/((\\w)(/\\3))/"
```

Or

```
p(<<~RUBY)
  #{%r{/((\w)(/\3))/}}
RUBY
# (?-mix:\\/((\\w)(\\/\\3))\\/)
```

The thing is I need the regex to be unescaped, and somehow be able to interpolate some other things onto the string.

Comment: If you `puts your_string`, what is it that you want to see on the screen? Note that `p` produces escaped output, which is not the same as what `puts` gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You answered your own question

```
puts <<~'RUBY'
  /((\w)(/\3))/
RUBY
# /((\w)(/\3))/
```

The single quotes around RUBY disable escapes so your string is interpreted literally.

`p` is not how you print strings, that's how you inspect an object for debugging purposes. For strings, that actually shows the string *with* escapes, such that you could copy and paste that representation into Ruby code and get the same string. Look:

```
puts "/((\\w)(/\\3))/"
# /((\w)(/\3))/
```

Comment: That something I really didn't know, thanks a lot :*

Comment: Technically, [Kernel#p](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Kernel.html#method-i-p) writes *obj*.inspect plus newline to standard output and returns *obj* as a escaped double-quoted string. It's a perfectly legitimate way to write output, provided you understand what object is being written. `p /((\w)(\3))/ #=> /((\w)(\3))/` works just fine.

Comment: Note that `/((\w)(/\3))/` is not a valid regular expression, because you have a stray forward slash in the middle of it.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs there are some classes for which `p` gives sensible output (arrays, numerical types, etc.) but in general I would not recommend it for printing something user-facing. `inspect` is for representing an object as a String, so unless your users care about specific object representations, you should use `to_s` and `puts`.